# dynamically setting scroll view's content size programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, uiscrollview

```
UIScrollView *scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]init];

//    scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(, <#CGFloat height#>)
[scrollView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
scrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

//    CAGradientLayer *bgLayer = [AddClusterViewController greyGradient];
//    bgLayer.frame = scrollView.bounds;
//    [scrollView.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];
//



NSLayoutConstraint *scrollViewLeft=[NSLayoutConstraint
                                    constraintWithItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:
                                    NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *scrollViewTop=[NSLayoutConstraint
                                   constraintWithItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:
                                   NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *scrollViewHeight=[NSLayoutConstraint
                                      constraintWithItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:
                                      NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:0];

NSLayoutConstraint *scrollViewWidth= [NSLayoutConstraint
                                      constraintWithItem:scrollView
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                      toItem:self.view attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                      multiplier:1.0
                                      constant:0];

[self.view addConstraints:@[scrollViewTop,scrollViewLeft,scrollViewWidth,scrollViewHeight]];

UIView *inView=[[UIView alloc]init];

[inView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

inView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

self.clusterNameText=[[UITextField alloc]init];
self.clusterNameText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.clusterNameText.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
self.clusterNameText.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
self.clusterNameText.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
self.clusterNameText.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor cyanColor]CGColor];
self.clusterNameText.delegate=self;
self.clusterNameText.layer.borderWidth=0.5;
[self.clusterNameText setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

self.clusterNameText.attributedPlaceholder =
[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Enter Cluster Name"
                                attributes:@{
                                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor grayColor],
                                             NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Baskerville-Italic" size:17.0]
                                             }
 ];

[inView addSubview:self.clusterNameText];
NSLayoutConstraint *clusterNameTextConstraintLeft=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.clusterNameText attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:inView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:10];

NSLayoutConstraint *clusterNameTextConstraintTop=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.clusterNameText attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:inView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:100];

NSLayoutConstraint *clusterNameTextConstraintRight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.clusterNameText attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: inView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0f constant:-10];

[inView addConstraints:@[clusterNameTextConstraintLeft,clusterNameTextConstraintTop,clusterNameTextConstraintRight]];


//getting lastname
UILabel *settingLabel=[[UILabel alloc]init];
[settingLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[inView addSubview:settingLabel];
// settingLabel.text=@"ANALYSIS REPORT NOTIFICATION";
settingLabel.attributedText= [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"NOTIFICATION SETTING"
                                                             attributes:@{
                                                                          NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor cyanColor],
                                                                          NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"ChalkboardSE-Bold" size:17.0]
                                                                          }
                              ];


NSLayoutConstraint * settingLabelConstraintLeft = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                   constraintWithItem: settingLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:inView attribute:
                                                   NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:12];
NSLayoutConstraint * settingLabelConstraintTop= [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                 constraintWithItem: settingLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.clusterNameText attribute:
                                                 NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:30];
NSLayoutConstraint * settingLabelConstraintWidth= [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                   constraintWithItem: settingLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:inView attribute:
                                                   NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:-10];


[inView addConstraints:@[settingLabelConstraintLeft,settingLabelConstraintTop,settingLabelConstraintWidth]];


UILabel *dailyLabel=[[UILabel alloc]init];
[dailyLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[inView addSubview:dailyLabel];
dailyLabel.attributedText= [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Daily Report"
                                                           attributes:@{
                                                                        NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor cyanColor],
                                                                        NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"BradleyHandITCTT-Bold" size:17.0]
                                                                        }
                            ];


NSLayoutConstraint *dailyLabelConstraintLeft = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                constraintWithItem:dailyLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:inView attribute:
                                                NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:12];
NSLayoutConstraint *dailyLabelConstraintTop= [NSLayoutConstraint
                                              constraintWithItem:dailyLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:settingLabel attribute:
                                              NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:30];
NSLayoutConstraint *dailyLabelConstraintWidth= [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                constraintWithItem:dailyLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:inView attribute:
                                                NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:0.5 constant:0];

[inView addConstraints:@[dailyLabelConstraintLeft,dailyLabelConstraintTop,dailyLabelConstraintWidth]];


self.dailySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc]init];
[self.dailySwitch setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[inView addSubview:self.dailySwitch];

self.dailySwitch.onTintColor=[UIColor cyanColor];
self.dailySwitch.tintColor=[UIColor grayColor];

NSLayoutConstraint *dailySwitchConstraintLeft = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                 constraintWithItem:self.dailySwitch attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:dailyLabel attribute:
                                                 NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *dailySwitchConstraintTop= [NSLayoutConstraint
                                               constraintWithItem:self.dailySwitch attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:settingLabel attribute:
                                               NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:25];

[inView addConstraints:@[dailySwitchConstraintLeft,dailySwitchConstraintTop]];

[self.dailySwitch addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(stateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

UILabel *weeklyLabel=[[UILabel alloc]init];
[weeklyLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[inView addSubview:weeklyLabel];
weeklyLabel.attributedText= [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Weekly Report"
                                                            attributes:@{
                                                                         NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor cyanColor],
                                                                         NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"BradleyHandITCTT-Bold" size:17.0]
                                                                         }
                             ];


NSLayoutConstraint *weeklyLabelConstraintLeft = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                 constraintWithItem:weeklyLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:inView attribute:
                                                 NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:12];
NSLayoutConstraint *weeklyLabelConstraintTop= [NSLayoutConstraint
                                               constraintWithItem:weeklyLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:dailyLabel attribute:
                                               NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:36];
NSLayoutConstraint *weeklyLabelConstraintWidth= [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                 constraintWithItem:weeklyLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:inView attribute:
                                                 NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:0.5 constant:0];

[inView addConstraints:@[weeklyLabelConstraintLeft,weeklyLabelConstraintTop,weeklyLabelConstraintWidth]];


self.weeklySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc]init];
[self.weeklySwitch setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[inView addSubview:self.weeklySwitch];

self.weeklySwitch.onTintColor=[UIColor cyanColor];
self.weeklySwitch.tintColor=[UIColor grayColor];

NSLayoutConstraint *weeklySwitchConstraintLeft = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                  constraintWithItem:self.weeklySwitch attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:weeklyLabel attribute:
                                                  NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *weeklySwitchConstraintTop= [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                constraintWithItem:self.weeklySwitch attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.dailySwitch attribute:
                                                NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:25];

[inView addConstraints:@[weeklySwitchConstraintLeft,weeklySwitchConstraintTop]];
[self.weeklySwitch addTarget:self
                      action:@selector(stateChanged1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
myPickerView.dataSource = self;
myPickerView.delegate = self;
myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
[myPickerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

self.countryNameText=[[UITextField alloc]init];
self.countryNameText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.countryNameText.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
self.countryNameText.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
self.countryNameText.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
self.countryNameText.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor cyanColor]CGColor];
self.countryNameText.layer.borderWidth=0.5;
[self.countryNameText setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
self.countryNameText.inputView=myPickerView;
self.countryNameText.delegate=self;
self.countryNameText.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

self.countryNameText.attributedPlaceholder =
[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Choose Country"
                                attributes:@{
                                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor grayColor],
                                             NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Baskerville-Italic" size:17.0]
                                             }
 ];

[inView addSubview:self.countryNameText];
NSLayoutConstraint *countryNameTextConstraintLeft=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.countryNameText attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:inView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:10];

NSLayoutConstraint *countryNameTextConstraintTop=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.countryNameText attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:weeklyLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:30];

NSLayoutConstraint *countryNameTextConstraintRight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.countryNameText attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: inView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0f constant:-10];

[inView addConstraints:@[countryNameTextConstraintLeft,countryNameTextConstraintTop,countryNameTextConstraintRight]];


[scrollView addSubview:inView];

NSLayoutConstraint *inViewLeft=[NSLayoutConstraint
                                constraintWithItem:inView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:scrollView attribute:
                                NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *inViewTop=[NSLayoutConstraint
                               constraintWithItem:inView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:scrollView attribute:
                               NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *inViewBottom=[NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:inView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.countryNameText attribute:
                                  NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:20];

NSLayoutConstraint *inViewWidth= [NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:inView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:scrollView attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                  multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:0];



[scrollView addConstraints:@[inViewTop,inViewLeft,inViewWidth,inViewBottom]];


[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height*2)];
```

This is my scroll view...am new to ios..now i dont want to explicity give the content size of scroll view..and my requirement is to dynamically change the textview size based on content to which scroll view also has to be changed..how to do it...or please  suggest some good tutorials on scroll view with autolayout..i am not using story board and i need everything programatically....any help will be appreciated...thanks in advance

2017-04-06 12:56:54.030 AppAdvisor[5899:325423] inView height 0.000000 inView width 0.000000
2017-04-06 12:56:54.030 AppAdvisor[5899:325423] scroll height 0.000000 scroll width 0.000000
2017-04-06 12:56:54.030 AppAdvisor[5899:325423] contentsize height 1704.000000 contentsize width 320.000000

Comment: Try with replacing your last code line with this: 
`[scrollView setContentSize: inView.frame.size];`

Comment: Where is the `textView`? Is it inside the `UIScrollView`?

Comment: i didn't include text view yet...dynamically changing the textview height is done....but what i am not able to do is how to calculate the content size of scroll view

Comment: Yes i tried inView.frame.size.height that too...its not working but logically it has to work...i dont know why its not working @Mrunal

Comment: Can you print your inView frame and ScrollView content size and Scrollview frame and copy it to your question here

Comment: Try to add Height Constraint for each subviews of inView and set the priority for that height constraint.

Comment: If you wish to simply add a `UITextView` inside a `UIScrollView`, there is no need for that...`UITextView` is inherently scrollable. Soo all you need to do is update the height of the `UITextView`. If the content inside exceeds the `UITextView` height, it will become scrollable on its own. If you are adding other views, please update your question what exactly you are trying to achieve! As if there are other views, then the constraints to be added to the `UITextView` will change. `UIScrollView` can infer its contentsize based on items inside it, if autoLayout has been used properly.

Comment: am using multiple views other than textview...sorry to confuse about the question...all i need is the above code to work without setting content size...but its not working...as u said i might done some mistake in autolayout and that is the thing i cant get....please any advise will be appreciated

Comment: Like I said, more information is needed regarding the other views and what you are trying to achieve to suggest the correct constraints!